# How to compare a user input to a random output of a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare the input of the user with the answer that the computer prints from the list. Does anyone know why my if statements aren't working?

```
import random

while True:

    def rps():
        user = input("Rock Paper Scissors: ")
        answers = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        print(random.choice(answers))

        if user == "r" and answers == "Rock":
            print("Tie")

        if user == "r" and answers == "Paper":
            print("You Lose")

        if user == "r" and answers == "Scissors":
            print("You Win")

    rps()
```

Comment: Print out `answers` before the `if`s. What you do get? Then think about if `answers == "Rock"` makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a variable to the random choice, like this:

```
import random

while True:

    def rps():
        user = input("Rock Paper Scissors: ")
        answers = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
        choice = random.choice(answers)
        print(choice)

        if user == "r" and choice == "Rock":
            print("Tie")

        if user == "r" and choice == "Paper":
            print("You Lose")

        if user == "r" and choice == "Scissors":
            print("You Win")

    rps()
```

Be sure to add more logic for other user inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Did you want a program like this?

I configured your code a bit

```
import random

answers = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
options = ['r', 'p', 's', 'q']

def rps():
    while True:

        print("[r] Rock")
        print("[p] Paper")
        print("[s] Scissors")
        print("[q] Exit")
        user = input("Enter your choice: ")
        if user not in options:
            print("Wrong choice, try again.")
            continue
        choice = random.choice(answers)
        print('Computer answer: ', choice)

        if user == 'r':
            if choice == "Rock":
                print("Tie")
            elif choice == "Paper":
                print("You lose")
            else:
                print("You win")
        elif user == 'p':
            if choice == "Rock":
                print("You win")
            elif choice == "Paper":
                print("Tie")
            else:
                print("You lose")
        elif user == 's':
            if choice == "Rock":
                print("You lose")
            elif choice == "Paper":
                print("You win")
            else:
                print("Tie")
        else:
            break

rps()
```